# Split Column on regex

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I really struggle with regex, and I'm hoping for some help.

I have columns that look like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Location': ['Building A, 100 First St City, State', 'Fire Station # 100, 2 Apple Row, City, State Zip', 'Church , 134 Baker Rd City, State']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                                          Location
0              Building A, 100 First St City, State
1  Fire Station # 100, 2 Apple Row, City, State Zip
2                 Church , 134 Baker Rd City, State
```

I would like to get it to the code chunk below by splitting anytime there is a comma followed by space and then a number.  However, I'm running into an issue where I'm removing the number.

```
        Location Name                        Address
0          Building A       100 First St City, State
1  Fire Station # 100  2 Apple Row, City, State, Zip
2              Church       134 Baker Rd City, State
```

This is the code I've been using

```
df['Location Name']= df['Location'].str.split('.,\s\d', expand=True)[0]
df['Address']= df['Location'].str.split('.,\s\d', expand=True)[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.extract`:

```py
df[['Location Name','Address']] = df['Location'].str.extract(r'^(.*?),\s(\d.*)', expand=True)
```

The `^(.*?),\s(\d.*)` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 ('Location Name'): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `,\s` - comma and whitespace
- `(\d.*)` - Group 1 ('Address'): digit and the rest of the line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN4GFc/1).

Comment: thank you for explaining it!  I really stuggle to wrap my head around regex, and the website you suggested came up in my searches, but I it won't load for me.  I'll take a look later.

Comment: @pkpto39 Yes, the site is helpful to understand regex patterns. Here, keep in mind the number of capturing groups in the regex must be equal to the number of columns extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution to your problem is to use a positive lookahead. You want to check if there is a number *ahead* of your pattern, while not including the number in the match. Here's an example of a regex that solves your problem:

```
\s?,\s(?=\d)
```

Here, we optionally remove a trailing whitespace, then match a comma followed by whitespace.

The `(?= )` is a positive lookahead, in this case we check for a following digit. If that's matched, the split will remove the comma and whitespace only.